# How to interpret the output of choicemodelr (rhierMnlRwMixture) in R

Tags: r, output, bayesian, multinomial

### My Problem

I just started using the R library 'choicemodelr' and succeded in getting some beta values as a solution. But I wonder how do I assign these values to the specific attribute-levels. As a result I only get values for A1B1, A1B2, A1B3,... etc. How does this generic output generally connect to my Design?

Didn't find a hint in the documentation. Neither for the choicemodelr libraray, nor the bayesm library (rhierMnlRwMixture) to which it is connected to. I hope you can help me with this one.

Thanks in advance,
Phil

to illustrate this, some code and output:

### my code in R

```
# loading neccesary librarys
library(bayesm)
library(MASS)
library(lattice)
library(Matrix)
library(ChoiceModelR)
library(XLConnect)

#DATENSATZ:
setwd("C:/DATA/CBC/")   # set workingdirectory
.Workbook <- loadWorkbook("DataCBC-R2.xls")
data <- data.frame(readWorksheet(.Workbook, "DataCBC-R"))
remove(.Workbook)

#set parameter for calculation
R = 50000 #Total Iterations of the Markov Chain Monte Carlo
use = 100 #Iterations for Paramerter-Estimation

#Parameter of datainput
none = TRUE #TRUE, if the questionaire has a none-Option but is not coded in the data
xcoding = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1) #0=nominal scale; 1=metric scale

#Parameter dataoutput
save = TRUE #TRUE saves the calculated parameters
keep = 500 #number of random parameter draws to save (thinnig Parameter)

mcmc = list (R=R, use=use)
options = list(none=none, save=save, keep=keep, restart=restart)

#final calculation of the betas
out = choicemodelr(data, xcoding, mcmc = mcmc, demos = demos, options = options, constraints = constraints)
```

### I get the following Output (excerpt):

Resp    A1B1    A1B2    A1B3    A1B4    A2B1    A2B2    NONE
001 -2,56   -6,54   -18,49  27,59   -1,74   1,74    -1,94
002 -3,18   -6,52   -19,79  29,49   0,50    -0,50   -0,58

Hope that piece of information helps. Let me know, if you need further information.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us an example of your code and output?

Comment: sure. I edited my post. Unfortunately I wasn't able to post a picture (to few reputation-points) nor use a html table. Hope you can still read it.

Comment: Could we see an example of what the data frame data looks like?

Comment: Of course. I started a post on the 'cross validated' forum. Seems that I forgot to link it with this one. Sorry for that. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85362/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-choicemodelr-rhiermnlrwmixture-in-r/86102#86102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the complete answer at *cross validated* (where it should have been in the first place): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85362/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-choicemodelr-rhiermnlrwmixture-in-r/86102#86102

Answer (score 0):

Here is the input data:

```
respondent  choice-set  stimulus   Attr. Color  Attr. Shape  Choice
1           1           1          1            2            1
1           1           2          3            1            0
1           1           3          2            1            0
1           2           1          1            2            4
1           2           2          3            1            0
1           2           3          2            1            0
1           3           1          4            1            3
1           3           2          1            2            0
1           3           3          3            1            0
1           4           1          2            1            2
...        ...         ...        ...          ...          ...
```